# Use Condition In Where Clause In Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How Can I use Condition in Where Clause?

user can select section,product and model from list and see the result.
i add an item `See All` in all the filed,if user select `See All`,he can see all product in all section.so i want to write 
a query that check for value if every property equal -1 dot bring in where condition.

```
//My Model
struct Model
{
public int SectionCode{get;set;}
public int ProductCode{get;set;}
public int ModelCode{get;set;}
}

var query=DBContext.Model.Where(data=>data.ModelCode==_ModelCode//if ModelCode!=-1 
&& ProductCode==_ProductCode//if ProductCode!=-1  
&& SectionCode==_SectionCode//if SectionCode!=-1 )
```

I know that i can write it with some `if` but i have to check a lot of condition.so i want to know, how can i write if in where Clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
var query=DBContext.Model.Where(data => (ModelCode == -1 || data.ModelCode == _ModelCode) 
&& (ProductCode == -1 || ProductCode == _ProductCode)
&& (SectionCode == -1 || SectionCode == _SectionCode)
```

Answer (score 9):

Just don't add a where clause if you don't need it, i.e:

```
IQueryable<Model> query = DBContext.Model;

if(_ModelCode != -1)
{
    query = query.Where(data=>data.ModelCode==_ModelCode);
} 

if(_ProductCode!= -1)
{
    query = query.Where(data=>data.ProductCode==_ProductCode);
} 

if(_SectionCode!= -1)
{
    query = query.Where(data=>data.SectionCode==_SectionCode);
}
```

Comment: +1: This is a better answer than mine. However, it will probably not compile if you don't specify the query type explicitly.

Comment: @IRSOG the where clauses in the query are chained - i.e. you first filter by _ModelCode if it's not -1 then you filter the result of the first filtering by _ProductCode if it's not -1 then you filter the result by _SectionCode if it's not -1. if " _ProductCode and _SectionCode was -1" you'll only have your models filterred by ModelCode. If _ProductCode and _ModelCode are NOT -1 both then your query will be filterred by both _ProductCode and _ModelCode

Comment: @IRSOG in other words, it "skips condtion for each item that is -1"

Comment: @Douglas , thanks! I believe it should compile as is (I expect DBContext.Model to be of IQueryable<Model>), although I didn't try this particular example of course.

Comment: @Isantipov: It depends on the ORM technology. LINQ-to-SQL returns a concrete type that implements `IQueryable<Model>`, which would need to be cast to the interface for the `var` declaration to permit further re-assignments.

Comment: @Douglas , aha, I get what you mean now! I'll edit the sample.

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve this using logical operators:

```
var query = DBContext.Model.Where(data =>
    (_ModelCode   == -1 || data.ModelCode == _ModelCode)
 && (_ProductCode == -1 || data.ProductCode == _ProductCode)
 && (_SectionCode == -1 || data.SectionCode == _SectionCode))
```